# WPF C# OpenFileDialog ReadOnlyChecked

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to open a Windows 10 style open file dialog box with the Read only option set. I have set the ShowReadOnly and ReadOnlyChecked to true but the read only check box doesn't appear. I am using Win32 Open File dialog box.
If I use Win Forms Open file dialog box I get an XP style box with the read only option visible. I want to stick with Win32.

How do I show the Read only option with Win32 Open file dialog box?

```
         openFileDialog.ShowReadOnly = true;
         openFileDialog.ReadOnlyChecked = true;
         bool? retVal = openFileDialog.ShowDialog();
```